# Schedule (Cron) executing tasks based on bash scripts using CronniX

Tags: shell, shell-script, osx, macintosh

*I'm still quite new you Mac and OS X but do have some background about other UNIX based systems, so please excuse for any misunderstandings.*

My goal is to implement a function that executes certain tasks at certain times, a typical cron job behaviour. For example, I'd like to backup a specific directory once a month and move it into my Google Drive directory.

All these scripts (bash) are there and work when executing them via the terminal. I used the `.bash_profile` file in my home directory to scan the directory containing the scripts, making them executable and added them to the `$PATH` global so that I can call them directly via the terminal, using this:

```
## Make scripts executables
for file in `find $HOME/Scripts/Bash -name '*'`; do
    chmod +x $file;
done

## Include custom bash scripts
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Scripts/Bash
```

However, my goal now is to schedule the execution of these tasks. I've stumbled upon CronniX which is exactly was I had been looking for. Unfortunately the commands that work in the terminal no longer work in CronniX.

Here are two screenshots with a sample custom function (`ttouch`; it does the same as `touch`) to compare:

[image: 1. After using <code>ttouch</code> in terminal. File successfully created.]

**Above:** After using `ttouch` in terminal. File successfully created.

[image: 2. Using CronniX with the same command as used in terminal. No file created. Same happens with <code>sudo</code> prepended.]

**Above:** Using CronniX with the same command as used in terminal. No file created. Same happens with `sudo` prepended.

**So, my final question:** Does anyone know how I can achieve this scheduling process? Your help would be much appreciated.